# NullPointerException on getInputstream

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, inputstream, urlconnection

Do you know why I'm catching the NullPointerException when I call the getInputStream() function?

I did a Log of the URLConnection and the link is correct...I can't figure out what's the problem.

```
public Bitmap getBitmap(String resolution) {
    URL url = null;
    Bitmap bmp = null;

    switch(resolution) {
        case "thumb":
            url = thumbUrl;
            break;

        case "low":
            url = lowresUrl;
            break;

        case "standard":
            url = standardresUrl;
            break;
    }

    try {

        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

        in.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bmp;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all the answers.
The problem was inside the catch block in this line:

```
Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
```

The getMessage() function was returning null.

Comment: Further to this conversation, I was having the exact same issue as Michele. e.getMessage() was indeed returning null. Log.e throws an exception when you send it null, so to determine what exception was being thrown, I modified the statement to: Log.e("Error", e.toString()); and the exception turned out to be a "Network:android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException", for me in any case. After some reading I found out that you can't run blocking IO calls on the main UI Thread which makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Given your posted code, the only reasonable conclusion is that `conn` is `null`. You can check for that using a [conditional operator `? :`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) (ternary) like

```
// InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
InputStream in = (conn != null) ? conn.getInputStream() : null;
```

or something like

```
InputStream in = null;
if (conn != null) { 
    in = conn.getInputStream();
}
```

I also note that your `switch` doesn't have a `default:`, so it's also possible that `url` is  `null` (but you'd get an `Exception` on `openConnection()` if that were the case).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i mentioned that I did a log of String.valueOf(conn) object and it's not null.
By the way I tried your solution, and I can confirm that the URLConnection isn't null.

Comment: In which line are you getting the NullPunterException?

Comment: You must be mistaken, or you call it more than once. For the method call to throw a npe, the instance you are trying to call it on must be null.

Comment: I'm sorry. The npe was thrown con the e.getMessage().
But continue to get error in the getInputStream() line.
Maybe I have to start another question from scratch

Answer (score 0):

Declare and initialize your variable before try-catch.
In java programming don't try to declare variable in try catch.Do it before try catch.

```
    URLConnection conn=null;
    InputStream in=null;
    try {

    conn = url.openConnection();

    in = conn.getInputStream();

    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

    in.close();

}
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems that the problem was that the e.getMessage() returned null

Comment: The problem is not about e.getMessage(). If there is a mistake in try part then the catch part is working. The problem is in your try part.When you write java program declare your variable before try part and initialize to null.